# Regex to capture blank value of a key

Tags: regular-expression, python3

I am trying to capture value of "Comment" from below input strings and `regex = ^comment[\s*:]*(.*)`
But i'm getting below output:
**"comment": "probe cycle errors      : 0"**

```
No of Host Probes       : 0
Max no of Host Probes   : 0
rstIsFailure            : 1
state                   : UNKNOW
comment                 :  
probe cycle errors      : 0
Perf Callback Ids       : None
Group Member            : __jjjjkj - U0
```

EXpected output: `comment                 :`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `sed`, and assuming you don't want the first blank character after the `:`:

```bsh
sed '/^comment/!d; s/[^:]*:[[:blank:]]//' file
```

or, with only a single editing statement,

```bsh
sed -n 's/^comment[[:blank:]]*:[[:blank:]]\(.*\)/\1/p' file
```

In Python, I suppose that would look like

```
^comment[[:blank:]]*:[[:blank:]](.*)
```

or possibly

```
^comment\s*:\s(.*)
```

if Python doesn't understand POSIX character classes.

The `[[:blank:]]*` bit  matches any run of spaces or tab characters. The `\s` pattern is more like the POSIX `[[:space:]]` character class, which matches a wider array of space-like characters, including newlines.

---

The issue with your expression is that you're matching against the whole document in a string and that in Python (which I presume you're using), `\s` matches the embedded newline characters in the string (the string that is the whole document).  The expression therefore captures everything from the first non-space (newlines included), non-`*`, non-`:` (both `:` and `*` are literal within `[...]`), character, which is the `p` in `probe` on the next line, up until the following newline.

Comment: It doesn't seem to support the `[[:alpha:]]` style classes, apparently (but there's an external library that does): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31915346/python-posix-character-class-in-regex [The documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) seems a bit inconsistent with the terminology, it refers to both `\x` and `[xyz]` as character classes, but also calls `[xyz]` a set. So, `\s` it is. Or `[ \t]`.

Comment: The issue with the user regex is that he placed the `\s` inside a `[]` (character class). What it does becomes clear at this link: https://regex101.com/r/kEAUnj/1

Answer (score 1):

**You can also make it the following:**

```
'^comment[\s*:]*(\S+| +)$'
```

Changed `.*` to `\S+` so that we are either matching any non whitespace OR the spaces (explained further below) followed by end of line or spaces followed by end of line.

The `| +)` is to also match any number of spaces (one or more) within the set.

The set is then expected to follow with an end of line to capture this scenario you are experiencing

Here's a screenshot illustrating the regex matching the conditions:

[image]